# useState is undefined on component unmount

Tags: reactjs

When the component is unmounted `connectionId.stop();` produces `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stop')`, though `connection.stop();` stops the connection. I suspect that when the component unmounts the useState is no longer there but the `var connection` is still there just before it unmounts.

I mean, if I call `connectionId.stop();` from a child component of this component, it stops the connection.

I could just use `var connection` but that doesn't seem the ReactJs way to do things?

```
const [connectionId, setConnectionId] = useState();

useEffect(() => {

    var connection;

    const fetchJoinedMessage = async () => {
        try {
            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("https://localhost:4581/chat")
                .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
                .build();

            await connection.start();
            setConnectionId(connection)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
    }

    fetchJoinedMessage()

     return () => {
         console.log("Component unmounted")

         console.log(connection) // displays the connection
         console.log(connectionId) // connectionId undefined
         //connection.stop(); // connection is stopped
         connectionId.stop(); // connection not stopped
     }

}, [])
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a ref instead

Comment: This happens because effect cleanup ("unmount") runs before the `connection.start()` promise is resolved and the state is set. You can add some `console.log`s to see the sequence of events.

Comment: @tromgy That doesn't make sense to me. The stuff in the return statement only runs when the component is unmounted/e.g on a button click.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why does useRef work but not useState?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need your `connectionId` on unmount to stop it, then declaring it as you did with connection is ok, consider using `let` instead of `var` tho